# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.restassured.RestAssured at net.serenitybdd.rest.SerenityRest.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation

Tags: selenium, rest-assured, cucumber-serenity

I am using Serenity+rest assured for my selenium test cases. But while doing maven install, I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.restassured.RestAssured
        at net.serenitybdd.rest.SerenityRest.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation(SerenityRest.java:272)
```

I am using Java 8 version. For serenity I am using 2.2.9 version and io.restassured version is 3.3.0.

Can you please suggest any workaround for this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

So which IDE are you using, I was using eclipse, what I found out it is that my Java environment was pointing to JRE 1.7, on pointing it correctly to JDK environment this got solved.

If you are running from cmd prompt then verify the jdk path on our system